# Uncaught TypeError: data.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, linq, d3.js

I'm using d3 to try to recreate a pie chart. Whenever I pass my data in (3 values), I get the aforementioned error. I believe I know the problem, the problem is that the 3 values are not mapped to anything. For example, when I tried this previously I mapped the values to SupplierID's and therefore it split into multiple different segments which was correct. However the values were wrong. I have now remedied the values, however they now are not mapped to anything and therefore will not display. Is there a way to get around this?

For example could I manually assign them an ID to map to? Or is there another way to get around this?

D3:

```
 <script>
        var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

        var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888"]);

        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .outerRadius(radius - 10)
            .innerRadius(0);

        var pie = d3.layout.pie()
            .sort(null)
            .value(function (d) { return d.QueryTotal; });

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
          .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

        var data = @Html.Raw(@Model.output);

        console.log(data);

            var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
                .data(pie(data))
              .enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "arc");

            g.append("path")
                .attr("d", arc)
                .style("fill", function (d) { return color("QueryTotal"); });

            g.append("text")
                .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(function (d) { return "QueryTotal"; });
    </script>
```

Data:

```
NormalTotal: 0
QueryTotal: 131058.34
StrongTotal: 0
```

LINQ:

```
public TotalValueBySupplierAndClaimTypeModel GetTotalValueBySupplierAndClaimType(int ClientID, int ReviewPeriodID, int StatusCategoryID) {
            var rt =
                this.GetValueBySupplierAndClaimType(ClientID, ReviewPeriodID, StatusCategoryID);

            TotalValueBySupplierAndClaimTypeModel x = new TotalValueBySupplierAndClaimTypeModel() {
                NormalTotal = rt.Sum(c=>c.Normal) ?? 0,
                QueryTotal = rt.Sum( c => c.Query) ?? 0,
                StrongTotal = rt.Sum( c => c.Strong) ?? 0
            };

            return x;
        }
```

UPDATE:
I need to assign an ID to each one of my values in my LINQ statement. I have the values in my viewModel. However, I'm not sure how to do this. Does anyone else?

Comment: In the question your Data is NormalTotal: 0 QueryTotal: 131058.34 StrongTotal: 0 , But In your script every where you are statically using QueryTotal, What kind of relation, Just kindly pay attention on what you are doing.... That will make you not to do wrong things. And one more thing is that you are getting data by calling @Html.Raw(@Model.output); And the fore mentioned error will come due to the passed argument is not an array, map function we can call on Array. k

Comment: I am paying attention to what I'm doing thank you. Right now I'm just trying to display QueryTotal. I want to get that to work and then move onto the other two. And I tried returning my data as an array, however. It add's 'quot;' for each one of my values which causes it to fail.

Comment: 'quot;' in the sense what, this same text or the value is converted into string..??

Comment: It converts a ' to the actual words quot;

Comment: So we need to convert that into number??

Comment: Convert the values into numbers, yes. But that data I receive back looks like the following: 'quot; QueryTotal quot; : 123

Comment: I know the problem. I need to return my data as an array and that will work. However, to do this I need to assign 3 keys to each Total. So there will be a QueryID, NormalID and a TotalID. But im not sure how to do this

Comment: That's not what I need to do. What I need to do is in LINQ assign an ID each value. However I'm not sure how I can do that